# git no history for special folder and files - just sync no revision

Tags: git

I have use case that i use BabelJS Webpack Flowjs and much more js preprocessor to build an application that source is in `src` directory and save the result in `dist` directory. the app folder is default source folder and want to git behavior default. but problem is `dist` directory with huge changes just increase git database size that i dont need the revisions.

```
app
 `- test.babel
 `- other.babel
dist
 `- test.js
 `- other.js
```

I want to git just sync my `dist` directory and don`t save the history of changes on`dist` directory.

If it's possible how any git configuration?
If it's not possible how can i have do my desire case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need it in your repository then if you don't want to track changes? Could you please elaborate on your question

Comment: @e.doroskevic i dont wanna create build server and need to git work for me as transfer my production code even in production server. cause of i dont need revision is to prevent increase git database size.

Comment: thank you for your response, myself - I'm not entirely sure still what is the objective you pursue. Since, the whole point of version control system is to conduct version control. Perhaps someone else will be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: So you are basically asking for a way to transfer the `dist/` folder from your local machine to a server?

Comment: @AnimiVulpis yeah no other dependency just simple trick for transfer as same protocol such as source

Comment: Wouldn't [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) be a better tool for the job?

Comment: @AnimiVulpis i dont wanna use another tools if i want `rsync` will be good choice